# What does this line mean ? (Logstash Conf & Grok Syntax)

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Hi i'm new to Logstash and Grok syntax, I'm trying to understand what are those line meaning

```
codec => multiline { pattern => "^{$" negate => "true" what => "previous" }
```

and

```
mutate {
                gsub => ["message", "'", '"']
        }
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is pretty well explain in the official documentation of the [`multiline` codec plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html):

- `pattern => ^{$` matches lines that only contain a `{` character and end immediately
- `negate => true` means that line NOT matching the pattern are considered
- `what => previous` means that the current matched line relates to the previous one

In summary, these settings mean that all lines that do NOT consist of only `{` belong to the previous line.

Concretely, this multiline filter is for putting together JSON data that was pretty-printed on several line, like this:

```
{
   "bla": {
       "test": 1
   }
}
```

The above pretty-printed JSON will be handled as if it had been printed as a single line, like this:

```
{ "bla": { "test": 1 } }
```

Regarding the second filter ([`mutate/gsub`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-gsub)), it is used to replace all single quotes with double quotes.